# Visual Studio 2013 Reference Hell - It keeps finding an older version of the DLL that does not exist anyhwere - Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have some Source Code that I place on a shared drive, that is mapped to the F drive.

I have a bunch of assemblies, that I built, located here:  F:\Development\OurProject\Assemblies\Projects\Release

Inside this folder is this particular dll:  **Common.Themes.dll** (and the corresponding Common.Themes.pdb).  I just performed a full build last night, so both are dated 10/22/2018 7:47 PM.  The dll has a Product Version and File Version of 5.0.6869.33817

In this VM, that I develop in, I have a C: drive.  I just searched this drive for any Common.Themes.dll, so I can delete them off of this C: drive.  I even closed down all my projects so that I could delete any dll's found here: C:\Users\justlooking\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectAssemblies

And I also deleted everything from: C:\Users\justlooking\AppData\Local\Temp\

The only instances of that dll/pdb on this computer is here:  C:\Users\justlooking\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyThemeTest\

Anyhoo ...

On this F drive I have the following solution here: F:\Development\OurProject\UserProfiles\UserProfiles.sln

In this solution we have two project files\folders here:

F:\Development\OurProject\UserProfiles\UserProfiles

F:\Development\OurProject\UserProfiles\TestContainer

Before I opened the solution, I deleted the bin/obj folders from both locations (TestContainer is the startup project - and UserProfiles does not reference this DLL).

As I mentioned, the TestContainer does reference Common.Themes.DLL.  And this morning I have deleted the reference and re-added it by browsing/navigating to the Assemblies folder, multiple times today.

Upon opening the Solution, the bin/obj folders are re-created, and if I go to the bin folder for TestContainer, and all references are placed there immediately.  Currently, I see **Common.Themes.DLL** with the 10/22/2018 7:47PM date.  SO FAR SO GOOD!

I go press the green play button (to debug/build the project) it also says Internet Explorer next to the green play button, as it will bring up IE by default.

After VS finishes building, I look in the TestContainer\bin folder and the 10/22/2018 7:47PM dll is replaced by one dated **10/9/2018 8:40PM**

The pdb is 10/22/2018 7:47PM, but the dll is 10/9/2018, a different size (obviously) and a different version (5.0.6856.35405).  An older version.  This is the only file that does this.

WHY OH WHY IS IT DOING THIS???  I CAN'T GET IT TO STOP.  I HAVE NO IDEA WHERE IT IS GETTING IT FROM AND HOW.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the path to your referenced DLL change after you do a debug build? Do any other referenced projects *also* have a reference to your Common.Themes.DLL?

Comment: After pressing the green play button, I select the reference from the solution explorer, and in the properties window for path it says: F:\Development\OurProject\Assemblies\Projects\Release\Common.Themes.dll   ... so no?  This is so odd.  I don't even know where it's getting this file.  This file doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: Though I wonder if it's F drive/share drive related.  Because in the past I've had an instance where I couldn't delete a file, because of some weird lock that won't go away, but that's not the case here.  I can delete the bin/obj folders.  And they don't reappear until I open the solution.

Comment: Open up the project config with notepad and see if there is any instructions for copying the file.

Comment: So, there's a huge mess of operations that happen when your application looks for  a DLL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications. But first, reboot your machine. Break all those potential VS-bug-driven file locks. If that doesn't work, look through that documentation.

Comment: I had opened the testcontainer .csproj file previously.  I didn't see any copy instructions, but I do see my reference:       <Reference Include="Common.Themes, Version=5.0.6869.33817, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\Projects\Release\Common.Themes.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>   ... that all looks right.

Comment: Use a good text editor to do a Find In Files for you solution directory and search every file in the solution  for Common.Themes.dll to see if any refereces to older versions are there. Try using sysinternals procmon to watch for the file events that place the older dll in the location you know, and see then if you can work out how it's coming to be there based on the name of the exe that is putting it there

Comment: LOL.  This is just f'ing painful and ridiculous.  Restarted the computer.  Twice.  Before opening solution, searched c drive.  Opened solution - bin folder re-created with the correct version.  Press Play button.  Old version appears.   AAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!  Onto @Cory's link, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, based on something @Caius Jard said, I did a "find in files" in the solution directory.  To my surprise, the TestContainer .csproj had Common.Theme referenced twice.

When I re-added the references I saw this get updated:

```
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="Common.Controls, Version=5.0.5493.35273, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\Projects\Release\Common.Controls.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Common.Themes, Version=5.0.6869.33817, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\Projects\Release\Common.Themes.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

All the correct versions, and the HintPath was using relative paths.  Cool.  And that's where I was focused when examining the .csproj file.

But now I realize if I scrolled to the bottom I see:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CustomReference Include="Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms">
    <HintPath>F:\Development\AWayOlderVersion\UserProfiles\TestContainer\bin\Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms.dll</HintPath>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </CustomReference>
  <CustomReference Include="Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms.Themes">
    <HintPath>F:\Development\AWayOlderVersion\UserProfiles\TestContainer\bin\Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms.Themes.dll</HintPath>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </CustomReference>
  <CustomReference Include="Common.Themes">
    <HintPath>F:\Development\AnOlderVersion\UserProfiles\TestContainer\bin\Common.Themes.dll</HintPath>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </CustomReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

F:\Development\AnOlderVersion\  ... still does exist.  So it was pulling it from there.

I don't understand why there are these "CustomReferences", and after deleting that ItemGroup (so all three customreference's), it seems to be working right.

Comment: When these projects were created, it was pre-Visual Studio 2013.  I wonder if that's some left-over from an older version of Visual Studio (even though I was using upgrade utilities to help me with my projects when I moved up)

Comment: It's one of those things that probably won't happen ever again in your entire career either.. :) but great that you got it solved!

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard ... If you want to chime in with something, outside of the comments, I'll hook you up with a green checkmark - as you did give me the idea to do the file search in the solution!

Comment: Knowing that it's appreciated and got some words of thanks is worth more to me than the points :)

Comment: That's great.  Thanks a lot.  It was very appreciated.